# How to add white edges around an image?

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know how to make it that there are some white edges around a picture.

Code:

````
<html>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<style>

.button {
  background-color: #1700e8;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 300px;
}





</style>
<body>

<img src="Selectie2.png" style= "position:inherit; top: -15px; left:100px width: 300px; height: 300px;">

<button class="button button1" style= "position:relative; top:-5px; left: 2px;">Gerrie Eijlers</button>
<button class="button button1" style= "position:relative; top:-5px; left: 26px;">Bart Ravensbergen</button>
<button class="button button1" style= "position:relative; top:-5px; left: 50px;">Alec Smit</button>
<button class="button button1" style= "position:relative; top:-5px; left: 74px;">Bobby Schagen</button>
<button class="button button1" style= "position:relative; top:-5px; left: 98px;">Dani Baijens</button>
<button class="button button1" style= "position:relative; top:-5px; left: 124px;">Ephrahim Jerry</button>

</body>

</html> ```
````

Comment: add
    outline: 6px solid white;
    outline-offset: -1px;
to the image style attribute
Edit the offset value to suit your requirement

Comment: You mean a border?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `border` css property like this:

```
img {
  border: #FFF solid 1px;
}
```

I would recommend adding an `id` attribute to your `<img>` tag so your style does not get applied to other images as well like I did below:

```
<img id ="someImg" src="Selectie2.png" alt="someImg" />

#someImg {
  border: #FFF solid 1px;
}
```

---

If you want a thicker or slimmer white border, just change the 1px value accordingly.

Comment: Also the `border-offset` property can be utilized to move the border closer or further from the image center.